# Android 12 startBluetoothSco not works once setMode to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION firstly by other app

Tags: android, bluetooth

#### Subject

`startBluetoothSco` do not work when audio mode was set to `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` firstly by other app on android 12 or higher.

#### Question

I want to let `startBluetoothSco` work even when it has been set to `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` firstly by another app

#### Steps

My test steps are as follows:

Connect the device with a Bluetooth headset,
open the first app, let the app set the audio mode to `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION`, and keep the recorder or player running. Code example:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

mAudioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                               44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                               AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                               11000);
mAudioRecord.startRecording();
```

Open the second app, and still set the audio mode to `AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION`, by the way, `startBluetoothSco`.

Then the second can not receive any Bluetooth broadcast and [SCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_protocols#Synchronous_Connection-Oriented_(SCO)_link) does not works.

However, when I kill the first app and rerun the second app, SCO works.

#### Analysis

According the source code, here is the code:

```
private CommunicationRouteClient topCommunicationRouteClient() {
    for (CommunicationRouteClient crc : mCommunicationRouteClients) {
        if (crc.getPid() == mModeOwnerPid) {
            return crc;
        }
    }
    if (!mCommunicationRouteClients.isEmpty() && mModeOwnerPid == 0) {
        return mCommunicationRouteClients.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

1. when the first app sets the mode to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION and when will become the mode owner
2. the second app runs `startBluetoothSco`, and will get null client, and then will do not start SCO.

```
private void onUpdateCommunicationRoute(String eventSource) {
    AudioDeviceAttributes preferredCommunicationDevice = preferredCommunicationDevice();
    if (AudioService.DEBUG_COMM_RTE) {
        Log.v(TAG, 
              "onUpdateCommunicationRoute, preferredCommunicationDevice: " +
                preferredCommunicationDevice + 
                " eventSource: " + 
                eventSource);
    }
    AudioService.sDeviceLogger.log((new AudioEventLogger.StringEvent(
            "onUpdateCommunicationRoute, preferredCommunicationDevice: " +
              preferredCommunicationDevice + " eventSource: " + eventSource)));

    if (preferredCommunicationDevice == null ||
        preferredCommunicationDevice.getType() !=
           AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_SCO) {

        AudioSystem.setParameters("BT_SCO=off");
    } else {
        AudioSystem.setParameters("BT_SCO=on");
    }
    if (preferredCommunicationDevice == null) {
        removePreferredDevicesForStrategySync(mCommunicationStrategyId);
        removePreferredDevicesForStrategySync(mAccessibilityStrategyId);
    } else {
        setPreferredDevicesForStrategySync(
            mCommunicationStrategyId,
            Arrays.asList(preferredCommunicationDevice));
        setPreferredDevicesForStrategySync(
            mAccessibilityStrategyId,
            Arrays.asList(preferredCommunicationDevice));
    }
    onUpdatePhoneStrategyDevice(preferredCommunicationDevice);
}
```

Comment: This is some foolproof mechanism. normally an app should set audio mode back to normal when done. Starting in Android 13 (API level 33), applications must migrate from AudioManager#startBluetoothSco() to AudioManager#setCommunicationDevice() starting at API level 31